# CSS - Targetting top nav ul li a:hover only

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

Ok, so I have a jsfiddle of my problem here:  http://jsfiddle.net/WF3QX/1/

Full Screen result is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/WF3QX/1/embedded/result/

I am trying to get rid of the box-shadow inset on `a:hover` of the submenu that pops up when hovering over the Menu 2 Item, but am not having any luck at all with this.  I'd rather just target the first `<ul> <li> <a>` elements and not the `<ul> <li> <ul> <li> <a>` elements.  I have tried this everyway I can think of by using `>` symbols to just grab the immediate children, but this doesn't seem to help at all.

HTML is as follows (within the `body` tag):

```
<nav id="main_menu" class="nav center">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a accesskey="1" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li class="current">
            <a accesskey="2" href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a accesskey="3" href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a accesskey="4" href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a accesskey="5" href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
        <li><a accesskey="6" href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
        <li><a accesskey="7" href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS is as follows:

```css
nav#main_menu {
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #A92A23;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-family: "MissionGothic-Regular", "Mission Gothic Regular Regular", "mission_gothicregular";
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -.3em;
    border-bottom: .15em solid #7c211c;
    border-top: .15em solid #7c211c;
    z-index: 1001;
}
ul.menu {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    margin: 0px;
}
nav#main_menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -.2em;
}
nav#main_menu ul.menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.2%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
nav#main_menu ul.menu li > a {
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    color: #f2efe9;
    background: #A92A23;
    line-height: 3em;
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #7c211c; */
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    /* ...and now override with proper CSS property */
    transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
}

nav#main_menu ul.menu li a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav#main_menu:first-child li {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
nav#main_menu ul.menu li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav#main_menu ul.menu li > a:hover, nav#main_menu ul.menu li > a:active, nav#main_menu ul.menu li.current > a {
    background-color: #f2efe9;
    color: #A92A23;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -0.2em 0px 0.15em -0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), inset 0px 0.7em 0.7em -0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: -0.2em 0px 0.15em -0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), inset 0px 0.7em 0.7em -0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: -0.2em 0px 0.15em -0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), inset 0px 0.7em 0.7em -0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
nav#main_menu ul.menu li.current > a {
    height: 3.15em;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
nav#main_menu a#pull {
    display: none;
}
.desc, .h4_desc, .desc_bold {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
li ul.sub_menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 3.1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background-color: #f2efe9 !important;
    border-bottom: .15em solid #605953;
    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
li.current ul.sub_menu li {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    float: none;
}
li.current:hover ul.sub_menu {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
li.current:hover ul.sub_menu li {
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav#main_menu ul.menu ul.sub_menu a { 
    padding: .5em .8em;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    width: auto !important;
    color: #A92A23 !important;
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    height: 0;
}
```

I don't want these CSS Rules effecting any other `ul` elements on the page, so I was kinda strict in the declaration of them.

Basically, what I am really trying to do is to drop down the `ul.sub_menu` with the `transition` css code on the height, when the user mouses over `Menu 2`, which isn't working.  But the other problem I am having, is how to get the `a:hover` only on the `nav#main_menu ul.menu li a:hover` elements and not the children `a:hover` elements of  `ul.sub_menu li`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of `nav#main_menu ul.menu li > a:hover, nav#main_menu ul.menu li > a:active` so the `box-shadow` class only remains on `nav#main_menu ul.menu li.current > a`.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WF3QX/3/

Update:

Make the selectors more specific:

`nav#main_menu ul.menu > li > a:hover, nav#main_menu ul.menu > li > a:active, nav#main_menu ul.menu > li.current > a`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WF3QX/5/

Comment: This is no good, cause this removes the effect on `hover` of the main menu, that I do not want to get rid of.  Just need to get rid of the `hover` on the sub menu links.

Comment: I need the box-shadow class for all `a:hover` of onlin the `#main_menu` li a elements, but need to get rid of it on the `ul.sub_menu a:hover`

Comment: OMG, yeah, that did it!  I was pulling my hair out on this 1!  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just forgetting to use an additional child selector to target the correct links in the first place:

```
nav#main_menu ul.menu > li > a
```